# Access properties of object literal within jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have an object literal as follows. In the `Init` method I set a handler for a click event. Later, when the handler is called, I want to access the `Bar` property using `this` keyword. At that point, `this` has the jQuery meaning.

Also, to make things clear, I don't want to implement functions inline with the selectors.

```
var StackOver = {

    Bar: "MyBarValue",

    Init: function(){
        $("#postId").click(this.Foo);
    },

    Foo: function(eventObject){
        // here **this** is jQuery keyword
        // how do I access StackOver.Bar?
    }
}
```

How do I access properties of this object literal inside `Foo`?

This could have been easy if I was using a constructor literal, which is not a go for me:

```
var StackOver = function (){
    var self = this;

    function bar()
    {
        // I can use self here
    }
}
```

**edit** I forgot to mention that I use the Revealing Module Pattern in this object literal, that hides private properties from the object.

Comment: Unless you plan on redefining it, you can simply reference it as... well, `StackOver.Bar`.  By the time the function is called, that should be well-defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option:

```
Init: function(){
    $("#postId").click(this.Foo.bind(this));
}
```

another option: (from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

```
Init: function(){
    $("#postId").click($.proxy(this.Foo, this));
}
```

**both of there take the `this` variable**  so you can't use `this` for other purposes

**if, however, you can't use `this`:**

```
Init: function(){
    $("#postId").click(function (self) {
        return function (event) {
            return self.Foo(self, event);
        }
    }(this));
}
```

and in Foo just add the `self` parameter.

```
Foo: function (self, event...) {
  ...
}
```

All that said, why can't you use `(function () {var self = this; ... }())` ?
It **is** the revealing module pattern, after all

Comment: it's available as `this`.

Comment: Sorry, I must've misunderstand. Inside `Foo` there is already the jQuery `this`. How do I access each of them using what you suggest?

Comment: `this` would be taken up by the `StackOver` object, see my edit if that is not a possibility

Answer (score 3):

Everyone else is suggesting `.bind`, which makes sense, but you also may just be able to reference the object itself in the closure:

```
Foo: function(eventObject) {
    console.log(StackOver.Bar);
}
```

Comment: good point, if it's a singleton, there's no need to worry about `this`

Comment: I use the Revealing Module Pattern, which I forgot to mention. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var StackOver = {
    /*...*/
    Init: function(){
        $("#postId").click(this.Foo.bind(this));
    },
    /*...*/
    Foo: function(eventObject){
        // here **this** was actually the html element
        // now it's the old this.
        alert(this.Bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: There.  Word of warning: `bind`ing a handler is tricky business if you `Init` more than once, with more than one object, or to more than one element.  Keep in mind that the handler referenced by the element itself is now storing your `this` pointer, not the `StackOver` object or the original function.  That is all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this has to be an object literal.  If you can use other structures, you could gain access through a revealing module like this:

```
var StackOver = (function() {
    var bar = "MyBarValue",
        init = function(){
            $("#postId").click(foo);
        },
        foo = function(eventObject) {
            // here `this` might be a jQuery wrapper object
            // but you can access `bar` directly.
        };

    return {
        Bar: bar, // Or not.  Do you really want this public?
        Init: init,
        Foo: foo
    }
}())
```

Comment: It is my personal preference based on my research

Comment: syntax error.  `var bar = "MyBarValue", init:`<--right there.  Not an object literal anymore.

Comment: Yes, I should have tested.  But the idea's clear enough I hope.  Code updated in any case.